# Weighting a length of time to get a different Date each time

Tags: sql

I have an arrival Date 01/01/2010, this has occurred 50 times and I want to randomise 50 departure dates using the length of stay weighting guide below, as you can the majority of these will leave 2 days later, but I cannot figure out how to write the code, Can you help.

```
LengthofStay LengthofStayWeighting
------------ ---------------------
1            1
2            5
3            4
4            3
5            3
6            3
7            3
8            1
9            1
10           1
```

I have started but have got stuck already

```
SELECT ArrivalDate,RAND(checksum(NEWID())) * LengthOfStay.LengthofStayWeighting AS Expr1, 
ArrivalDate + Expr1 as DepartureDate

FROM Bookings, LengthOfStay
ORDER BY ArrivalDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use DATEADD

```
SELECT ArrivalDate, DATEADD(day, RAND(checksum(NEWID())) * LengthOfStay.LengthofStayWeighting, ArrivalDate) AS DepartureDate    
FROM Bookings, LengthOfStay
ORDER BY ArrivalDate
```

**update**: Based on your comment, I think I misunderstood the question. Is this what you need?:

```
SELECT ArrivalDate, 
DATEADD(day, (select TOP 1 LengthofStayWeighting FROM LengthOfStay group by LengthofStayWeighting ORDER BY LengthofStayWeighting DESC), ArrivalDate) AS DepartureDate    
    FROM Bookings
    ORDER BY ArrivalDate
```

Basically you need to obtain the length that is repeated the most, in your case "1". If so, I think you need to include a FOREIGN Key..

```
SELECT ArrivalDate, 
DATEADD(day, (select TOP 1 LengthofStayWeighting FROM LengthOfStay l WHERE b.Id = l.BookingId GROUP BY LengthofStayWeighting  ORDER BY LengthofStayWeighting DESC), ArrivalDate) AS DepartureDate    
    FROM Bookings b
    ORDER BY ArrivalDate
```

Comment: Hi Carlos
The departure date must be always the day after the Arrival date how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry Carlos, its not you its me, I cannot seem to explain myself clearly when asking questions about SQL code. 
5% of stays will be for 1 Night
50% of stays will be for 2 Nights
30% of stays will be for 3,4,5,6,7 Nights
10% of stays will be for 8,9,10,11,12,13,14 Nights
5% of stays will be for 15 to 28 Nights
I just need to randomise the above percentages.
I hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pull numbers from a cumulative distribution.  This requires generating a random number and then pulling from the distribution.

The following code gives an example:

```
with LengthOfStay as (select 1 as LengthOfStay, 1 as LengthOfStayWeighting union all
                   select 2 as LengthOfStay, 5 union all
                   select 3, 4 union all
                   select 4, 4
                  ),
     Bookings as (select cast('2013-01-01' as DATETIME) as ArrivalDate),
     CumeLengthOfStay as
         (select los.*,
                 (select SUM(LengthOfStayWeighting) from LengthOfStay los2 where los2.LengthOfStay <= los.LengthOfStay
                 ) as cumeweighting
          from LengthOfStay los
         ) -- select * from CumeLengthOfStay
SELECT ArrivalDate, clos.LengthOfStay, randnum % sumweighting, sumweighting,
       ArrivalDate + clos.LengthOfStay as DepartureDate
FROM (select b.*, ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6))+0) as randnum
      from Bookings b
     ) b cross join
     (select SUM(LengthOfStayWeighting) as sumweighting from LengthOfStay) const left outer join
     CumeLengthOfStay clos
     on (b.randnum % const.sumweighting) between clos.cumeweighting - clos.LengthOfStayWeighting  and clos.cumeweighting - 1
ORDER BY ArrivalDate
```

Basically, you add up the weights, generate a random number less than the highest weight (using the `%` operator), and then look up this value in the cumulative sum of the weights.

Comment: Hi Gordon, That seems awfully complex for a simple dateadd query. I mean with the help of Carlos above I have got this far:

SELECT ArrivalDate, DATEADD(day, RAND(checksum(NEWID())) 
* LengthOfStay.LengthofStay, ArrivalDate) AS DepartureDate    
FROM Bookings, LengthOfStay

But I need the departure date to be the next day at the earliest not the same date.

Comment: @wafw1971 . . . Databases are not really designed specifically for pulling values from distributions.  They can do that.  But this query is not really that complex.  It is doing what is needed to pull from a distribution.

Comment: Hi Gordon

I have 1.31 Million lines of data already In my database this includes Arrival Date, Site and PitchType, what the next step is to populate the Departure date with a date too and this is randomised according to length of stay, for example 5% of stays will be for 1 Night 50% of stays will be for 2 Nights 30% of stays will be for 3,4,5,6,7 Nights 10% of stays will be for 8,9,10,11,12,13,14 Nights 5% of stays will be for 15 to 28 Nights. I hope I have explained this right. Thanks for your help.